# Dynamic property name assignments inside delegate

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I am trying to include a Settings object inside the delegate of a Repeater so that I can save the value of a SpinBox. However, I can't figure out how to dynamically set the property alias name.

What I want to achieve is to have the property alias name to be the same as the modelData. For example, for item1: "property alias item1: box.value"; for item2: "property alias item2: box.value", etc.

```
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
        delegate: RowLayout {
            Settings {
                fileName: "config"
                category: modelData
                property alias value: box.value
            }
            Label {
                text: modelData
            }
            SpinBox {
                id: box
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above generates the following settings, and is a work around to what I wanted to do:

```
[item1]
value=""
[item2]
value=""
[item3]
value=""
...
```

What I want is a single category with the values, like so:

```
[category]
item1=""
item2=""
item3=""
...
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: @eyllanesc Edited. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I observe that you are creating "n" Settings, and I suppose you want to have a Settings with "n" categories, and that in each category a value is saved, am I correct?

Comment: Kind of. See last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you cannot use properties but the [`value()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html#value-method) and [`setValue()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html#setValue-method) methods:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.settings

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    readonly property var values: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
    Settings {
        id: settings
        category: "category"
    }

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: values
            delegate: RowLayout {
                id: row_layout
                Label {
                    text: modelData
                }
                SpinBox {
                    id: box
                }
                Component.onCompleted: box.value = settings.value(modelData, 0)
                Component.onDestruction: settings.setValue(modelData, box.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[category]
item1=6
item2=6
item3=4
item4=2
item5=2
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Only thing I could mention is that I set the onValueChanged property of the box to save to the settings to replicate the alias behaviour.

Comment: @Vlad Yes, I know, I was going to add it but IMO it is unnecessary to save them at all times, I prefer that the load is at the beginning and save at the end.